# How to share image and text in objective c ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to share image and text in all `ActivityController` but the following code is not work for me:

```
NSString *theFileName = [[fileNameOfImage lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
//      [BDGSharing shareUsingActivityController:strDataForShare urlStr:@"google.com" image:_imageview1.image];


NSString *st = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",theFileName];
NSString *documentDirectory=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *saveImagePath=[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:st];
NSData *imageData2=UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imageview1.image);
[imageData2 writeToFile:saveImagePath atomically:YES];
NSURL *imageURL1=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:saveImagePath];
documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:imageURL1];
documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
documentInteractionController.name=strDataForShare;
 documentInteractionController.UTI = @"public.plain-text";
[documentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(1, 1, 1, 1) inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Please give me suggestion if any library or kit to share both on whatsapp.

Comment: You will need to explain what you expect to happen and what is happing instead or any error messages you are getting.

Comment: you want to use the activity controller?

Answer (score 0):

Let's review your code.
First-

```
NSString *st = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",theFileName];
NSData *imageData2=UIImagePNGRepresentation(_imageview1.image);
```

You are saving a .jpg image with PNG representation, shouldn't you use jpeg representation instead?

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_imageview.image, 1.0)
```

Second-

```
[imageData2 writeToFile:saveImagePath atomically:YES];
```

Right here you are not sure wether the image was saved successfully or not. Please add a condition

```
if([imageData2 writeToFile:saveImagePath atomically:YES]){

// here you are sure that the image was saved and you can use it.

}
```

Third-

```
documentInteractionController.UTI = @"public.plain-text";
```

You are sharing a jpg image, why is your UTI plain-text? Shouldn't it be `public.image`?

Just try to solve those issue and your code should work successfully.

Comment: thanks.. but i want to share image + text both from all activity controllers.. When i used this code i can only shared image from whats app and email also.?

Comment: As Far as I know there is no way to share both image and text to instagram via the UIDocumentInteractionController. Did you try using the instagram api?